# Android database backups

Tags: database, android, backup

I'm looking for ways to back up the database of my app on an Android phone. I know that SQLite databases are just files, so I'd expect to be able to just copy the file to SD-card if one is available.

However, I'm unsure as to how I'd prepare my database/activity for backup/restore.

When starting, my main activity reads the entries from one table in the database and displays them in a `ListView`. As shown in the API's "Notes" sample, I have a cursor that is automatically notified about changes to that table (`ListView` is automatically updated when I add/remove/update records in the table).

So: When I copy the database file to SD-card, I should not have a problem. But what if the user wants to restore a database file? I can't just copy the file back to the data folder, can I (EDIT: ... while a view displays data from the database and thus maybe holds an open connection)?

What would be "best practice" when implementing backup/restore? One approach I've considered is:

1. Open a special "restore" activity
   that holds no open database
   connections
2. Call `finish()` for the
   main activity to remove it and close
   database connections
3. Copy back the database file
4. Open a new "instance" of the main activity
5. Call `finish()` for the "restore" activity

Would that be the way to go? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But what if the user wants to restore a database file? I can't just copy the file back to the data folder, can I?

Yes, you can. As you can move the file *from* your data folder to a folder onto your SD card, you can move the file *back* from the SD card into your data folder.

What you proposed now, is a good approach, just keep in mind you do not want any open database objects during backup/restore.

Comment: What I meant is that I can not copy back the file when the view has an open connection. When I finish the view that retrieved data from the database, all connections should be closed, right?